# Is styling components like this a bad practice?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, styled-components

I would like to know whether this approach with `styled-components`, `nextjs`, `typescript` and `react`has any significant flaws or performance issues. I wanted to create a component that is not styled by default, and can be provided with CSS styles for each HTML element inside the component. I also needed to make sure that the CSS styles provided can work with the props the styled HTML elements will receive from the component. I will show some code:

*Repo can be found at: [Github link](https://github.com/JensMeindertsma/experiment-styled-components)*

**navigation.tsx**

```
import { ReactElement, memo, useMemo, useCallback } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import * as S from "./navigation.styles";
import { Style } from "../../types";

export type NavigationLinks = { [key: string]: string };

type Props = {
  styles?: {
    navigation: Style;
    link: Style;
  };
  links: NavigationLinks;
  currentRoute: string;
};

function Navigation({
  styles = { navigation: null, link: null },
  links,
  currentRoute,
}: Props): ReactElement {
  const generateNavigationLinks = useCallback(
    function(links: NavigationLinks) {
      return Object.keys(links).map((linkName) => {
        const href = links[linkName];
        const isCurrent = href === currentRoute;
        return (
          <Link key={linkName} href={href}>
            <S.Link styles={styles.link} active={isCurrent}>
              {linkName}
            </S.Link>
          </Link>
        );
      });
    },
    [currentRoute, styles.link]
  );

  const navLinks = useMemo(() => {
    return generateNavigationLinks(links);
  }, [generateNavigationLinks, links]);

  return <S.Navigation styles={styles.navigation}>{navLinks}</S.Navigation>;
}

export default memo(Navigation);
```

**navigation.styles.ts**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Style, ExportProps } from "../../types";

type Props = { styles: Style };

type Activatable = { active: boolean };

export const Navigation = styled.nav<Props>`
  ${(props): Style => props.styles}
`;

export type LinkProps = ExportProps<Props & Activatable>;
export const Link = styled.a<Props & Activatable>`
  ${(props): Style => props.styles}
`;
```

**index.tsx**

```
import { ReactElement, memo } from "react";
import * as S from "../styles/index.styles";
import Navigation, {
  NavigationLinks,
} from "../components/Navigation/navigation";

const navigationLinks: NavigationLinks = {
  Home: "/",
  Blog: "/blog",
  About: "/about",
};

const navigationStyles = {
  navigation: S.Navigation,
  link: S.Link,
};

type Props = { currentRoute: string };

function Home({ currentRoute }: Props): ReactElement {
  return (
    <>
      <Navigation
        links={navigationLinks}
        styles={navigationStyles}
        currentRoute={currentRoute}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default memo(Home);
```

**index.styles.ts**

```
import { css } from "styled-components";
import { LinkProps } from "../components/Navigation/navigation.styles";

export const Navigation = css`
  background-color: green;
`;

export const Link = css<LinkProps>`
  color: ${(props): string => (props.active ? "red" : "black")};
`;
```

I know that this is maybe a big question, but I just wanted to know whether is approach has any big issues or is considered an 'antipractice'.
Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Do you mean the whole css in js approach?

Comment: I am looking for a way to provide styling to a component that only contains logic. I'm using styled-components. I could wrap Navigation with styled() in index and style it that way, but I'm unsure how to style the nested JSX elements in the component like the <a> because the docs says using child selector in styling is an `escape hatch`. I would like to know what is the best way to style a u styled, logic-only component with styled-components.

Comment: I guess because you want to generate dynamic styles based on logic this would be a proper use-case! If you look at the ways we can style in react/next this is the best solution! We can use less/sass and conditions - we can use inline css  with conditions - we can use style components - we can use Layouts ( which is not useful in this case )

Comment: And as far as I know in UI libraries it is really suggested because you isolate the component with its style and no affection will happen while removing one component! Check this => https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-css-in-js-examples-pros-and-cons--cms-33574

Comment: But now when any of the styles change, it triggers a rerender to all the styles. Can you confirm this approach is not bad / bad for performance?

Comment: What is your recommended way to create components that don't have styling by default, and then supply styling to it from where it's used?

Comment: Rendered styles are cached. Compilation and DOM Rules creation happens only once.
based on = >https://cssinjs.org/performance/?v=v10.0.0

Answer (score 8):

Any classes used in styled components are not reusable throughout your application's context which is not DRY and defeats the purpose of CSS. Styled components are just as good as inline styles, no separation of concerns and the good old spaghetti code